# Force double quotes in phpMyAdmin export dump

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I have a `varchar` column in my table but when I export it in phpMyAdmin (4.6.6deb5ubuntu0.5), the values are quoted with single quotes. How do I force double quotes? I don't see a setting.

```
CREATE TABLE _temp (
  col1 SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  col2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

-- suboptimal dump.
INSERT INTO `_temp` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES
(1, 'L\'Amour Dure Trois Ans'),
…

-- desired.
INSERT INTO `_temp` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES
(1, "L'Amour Dure Trois Ans"),
…
```

Surprised there isn't a question like this on SO yet. Couldn't find anything in the [docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/) either.

I'm aware that I can find-and-replace after the fact. The question is how / whether you can prevent the suboptimal output in the first place.

I deem it suboptimal (not invalid) because I'd have liked to further work with the dump manually and the double quoted version is more human-readable / less error-prone. I am not looking for a permanent change; just a way to have one dump with custom settings.

I perform the export with Table › Export › Custom (SQL).

```
$ mysql --version — mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.34, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

mysql> SELECT @@version; — 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

Comment: Which database will you be importing the data into? Using double-quotes to encapsulate a string is generally not supported unless specifically configured as such. MySQL and MariaDB do support both `\'` and `''` as valid ways to escape a single quote.

Comment: "Using double-quotes to encapsulate a string is generally not supported" — Oh really? I did not know about that. I've been writing queries and DDL statements all the time now, without problem. I'm using MySQL 14.14 – I guess it came with preconfiguration, then. — I deem it suboptimal (not invalid) because I'd have liked to further work with the dump manually and the double quoted version is more human-readable / less error-prone. I wasn't looking for a permanent change either, btw; just a way to have one dump with custom settings.

Comment: How do you perform the "export"?  (There are multiple forms of export.)